# Sort complex XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have an xml structure that is complex and new xml files are created this way constantly. 
I am trying to sort the file so that it is in alphabetical order.
I am able to sort the Configuration type, but I also want to sort the "Sections" and "Parameters" inside.

### XML Input

```
<Document>
<Configurations>
    <Configuration type="TypeB">
        <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
        </Section>
        <Section name="TypeA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
        </Section>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration type="TypeA">
        <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
        </Section>
    </Configuration>
</Configurations>
</Document>
```

### Expected XML output

```
<Document>
<Configurations>
<Configuration type="TypeA">
        <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
        </Section>
    </Configuration>
    <Section name="TypeA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
        </Section>
    <Configuration type="TypeB">
        <Section name="SectionA">
        <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
        </Section>
    </Configuration>
</Configurations>
</Document>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">    
    <Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>                          
    </Document>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="Configurations">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Configuration" >
            <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." /> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Configurations/Configuration/Section">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Parameter" >
            <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>         
</xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="Adaptors">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Adaptor">
            <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How should the output look like? Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt you use `for-each` with `sort` and then a `copy-of` and an `apply-templates`, that causes the problem, if you use simply `apply-templates` with `sort`, that is, replace code like

```
   <xsl:for-each select="Configuration" >
        <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." /> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration">
  <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

then you should be able to get the result you want.

As you seem to want to sort always by the `type` attribute, I think you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*[*/@type]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to handle all such elements with one template. And additional identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should take care of the rest (for instance leaf elements with text content).

If you have other elements to be sorted by the `name` attribute then adding a template

```
<xsl:template match="*[*/@name]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should suffice.

Here is a complete sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*/@type]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*/@name]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
   <Adaptors>
      <Adaptor type="TypeB">
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
      </Adaptor>
      <Adaptor type="TypeA">
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
      </Adaptor>
   </Adaptors>
   <Configurations>
      <Configuration type="TypeB">
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
      </Configuration>
      <Configuration type="TypeA">
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
      </Configuration>
   </Configurations>
</Document>
```

into

```
<Document>

   <Adaptors>
      <Adaptor type="TypeA">
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
      </Adaptor>
      <Adaptor type="TypeB">
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
      </Adaptor>
   </Adaptors>

   <Configurations>
      <Configuration type="TypeA">
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
      </Configuration>
      <Configuration type="TypeB">
         <Section name="SectionA">
            <Parameter name="ParameterA"/>
         </Section>
         <Section name="SectionB">
            <Parameter name="ParameterB"/>
         </Section>
      </Configuration>
   </Configurations>

</Document>
```

Comment: Clearly the code that does `copy-of` and then `apply-templates` on the same input is wrong, and this answer fixes it. But the answer can be read as advice never to use `xsl:for-each` with `xsl:sort`. I'm not sure it was intended that way, but it's not advice I would ever give.

Comment: @MichaelKay, sorry, the line is meant as an introduction to the correction of the problem in the posted code, not as a general advice. I will try to reword it to make it clear that the statement refers to the approach taken in the code in the question.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I do have other nodes in my XML. I am sorting these fine, but I am still stuck on sorting the "Sections" and "Parameters" inside each of the "Configuration" and "Adaptor" sections.

Comment: @skaliam, I have added a template to show how the approach can be extended to sort other elements by `@name`. If you still have problems then edit your question and provide a short but unordered sample and the corresponding result you want.

Comment: @skaliam, if the answer solved your problem then consider accepting it.